# Analysis for many Categorical and one Continuous trait

Tags: statistics, relationship, bioinformatics, correlation, anova

My dataset contains multiple nominal non-binary variables (i.e- beak shape type, general eye position) which are represented/coded as numbers. For instance, for 'beak shape type' there are 4 options, 1-4, each representing a different shape. These variables are not ordered. I also have a single continuous variable - habitat humidity. I am trying to find a suitable analysis to illuminate the relationship between this continuous variable and the nominal ones. But I am new to stats and so am having trouble.

As far as I can tell, a multivariate regression is not suitable, as that would require for my categories to be ordinal/ranked.I also figured that getting a 'correlation coefficient' for this data wouldn't really make sense, as there would be no reason to assume a linear relationship between my 4 beak shape categories and my continuous variable. I tried 'MANCOVA', but it seems that this method treats all my nominal variables together as a single block, whereas I am looking to find the relationships for the individual variables. My current understanding is that 'ANOVA' is the best choice. I can do ANOVA for each variable and see it's relationship with the continuous variable.

I have performed an ANOVA in R on a few of my nominal variables. The results I get are Df, Sum Sq, Mean Sq, F value, Pr(>F) and Residuals. I don't really know the significance of these values except for that Pr(>F) is basically like a p value, telling me if the relationship is statistically significant. As far as I can tell, it doesn't really give me any value to quantify the strength of the relationship (or is the p value in this case basically telling me the strength of the relationship?). So, I also am considering that for each significant nominal variable, to get the mean habitat humidity for each of the categories within the variable. That way I can represent the relationship as: 'beak shape was highly significantly related to habitat humidity (p value here), and here is how it was related (show mean habitat humidity for each of the beak shape types)'. What do you think of my approach? Is ANOVA a suitable choice? Is this a reasonable approach to finding which of my nominal traits are the most related to the habitat humidity? Am I incorrect in what I have said/my thought process? As I am a beginner in stats, I would appreciate if you could tone down the technical jargon in your answers.

Comment: Interesting question, however, it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I see. Thanks, I will post it there.